# Name validation not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate name but this doesn't seem to be working. May I know where its wrong ? Nothing happens when I click on name. No alert displayed.

EDIT : My bad I typed it instead of copying it. I have corrected the brackets and everything. May I know If the logic is wrong here. 
I removed `.value` as mentioned still not getting to window alert.

```
  function Validation()
    {
        isValid = true;
        var x = document.forms["form1"]["FirstName"].value;
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if(x.value.match(alphaExp))
        {
            window.alert("Invalid FirstName, Enter again");
            isValid = false;
        } 

   if (!isValid)
        {
            window.alert("All Details Updated");
        }

        return isValid;
    }
 <form name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return Validation()">
```

Comment: Did you mean `valid = false` instead of `isValid = false`?

Comment: "but this doesn't seem to be working" --- what does this *exactly* mean? Fixing an issue starts with diagnosing.

Comment: @Marty Its corrected . Its same in my IDE.

Comment: `x.value` is wrong, because you used `.value` when you assigned to `x`.

Comment: Check your Javascript console for error messages. The answers pointed out that you have unbalanced braces, this would be reported as a syntax error.

Comment: Guys, his code isn't valid Javascript, isn't not even being evaluated, let alone run.

Comment: @Thrilok Just as an aside, you might want to consider setting isValid to false to begin with.  This errs on the side of caution.  It's usually better to not validate something that is valid that to validate something that isn't.  Nothing happens in the first case but in the second you may get your app into an insane state.

Comment: @Tibrogargan got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
    if(x.value.match(alphaExp))
```

You already used `.value` when setting `x`, it doesn't make sense to use it again when checking it. You should have gotten an error message in the Javascript console, saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

on that line.

It should be:

```
    if(x.match(alphaExp))
```

You also have your logic backwards. You should display the error message when the regexp **doesn't** match, and display "All details updated" when `isValid` is true (or just use `else`).

```js
function Validation() {
  isValid = true;
  var x = document.forms["form1"]["FirstName"].value;
  var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (!x.match(alphaExp)) {
    window.alert("Invalid FirstName, Enter again");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    window.alert("All Details Updated");
  }

  return isValid;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return Validation();">
  <input type="text" name="FirstName">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I am using netbeans nothing displayed.

Comment: Your `if` logics were backwards.